# Determine UI Language in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I determine the active UI language (eg English, German) in Google Apps Script for Google Sheets in an Add-On?

I want to use this language to show my sidebar in the same language.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetLocale()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSpreadsheetLocale()) to get spreadsheet locale or [`Session.getActiveUserLocale()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUserLocale()) to get locale of the user.